# Compile With Static Library Using GNAT

Tags: ada, gnat

To learn the processes behind compilation of Ada programs (without resorting to using `gpr`), I've decided to compile one of my projects manually. To compile a program, I run the following command on each `.adb` file therein (not manually, however):

> `$ gcc -c src/<file>.adb -o obj/<file>.o`

That compiles all the files and puts them in the `obj` directory.

Or rather, it would. There is a slight problem with this. I have an archive (static library) that I've generated from another project, called `libapples.a`, containing package `Apples`. The `Apples` package is used by the files you see me compiling above.

Since `libapples.a` doesn't have source files anymore (given its archive format), it's not viable (not even possible) to provide the sources of that library to the command above using `-I` switches; on the other hand, if I don't have the sources included, the command above comes back to me saying:

> `<file>.adb:<y>:<x>: file "apples.ads" not found`
>   `gnatmake: "src/<file>.adb" compilation error`

I've attempted to include the library in the compilation process by using flags `-L` and `l` (which I believe is how you'd do it in C; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong). In another attempt I placed the archive right in the source directory.

How does one go about including a library in the compilation process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apples.ads` is somewhat like a header in C and you definitely need it for your file to compile. You should use `-I` to point gcc to the directory where `apples.ads` is located in.

Be aware that compiling an Ada source not only yields an object file, but also an Ada Library Information (`.ali`) file. You'll need that for the next step. You should not use the `-o` flag because it may lead to your `.o` and `.ali` files having different names.

On the other hand, since you only want to produce an object file, you should use `-c` to tell gcc to only compile. In other languages like C, gcc compiles and links by default; in Ada, the process is more complex.

After compilation, you need to call `gnatbind` on the `.ali` file of your main program. This generates a package that will take care of proper initialization of everything. To do that, `gnatbind` needs the `.ali` file of the `Apples` package! You can specify the `.ali` search directory with `-aO`.

Finally, `gnatlink` called on the main `.ali` file will link everything together. It figures out itself which object files and libraries it needs. It will append the necessary options to the linker, including the reference to `libapples.a`. It also compiles the package generated by `gnatlink`.

I don't know exactly what `gnatlink` will do under the hood; you could probably compile the package generated by `gnatbind` manually and then call the linker if you can figure out the proper arguments.

Comment: The `-c` not being included in the command is a typo on my part. Thanks for spotting it! So, it's not possible to have a mere `.a` file on its own representing a library in Ada, then? You would need specification (`.ads`) files along with `.ali` files and the `.a` file containing the object files for the linking, correct?

Comment: You need the spec to tell the Ada compiler what’s available. Would you make a C application without having a `.h` file for the libraries it uses?

Comment: `.a` is always only the compiled object code, this part is not Ada-specific. It's the same in C, C++, and other compiled languages unless they compile to some intermediate code which retains that information (Java, C#).

Comment: I must confess, I've never had a clear use for libraries before. I always thought everything was kind of wrapped up inside the library file. :-) However it may be, +1 for the comments.